# How to generate .edmx from existing sql Server Database programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i have an existant database ,and i want to know how to generate the model (.edmx) automatically from the controller .
The question is how to generate the .edmx from a database with a bloc of code without using the wizzard if is it possible?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? How would you use it? It sounds like you want to generate it at run-time, which sounds rather odd.

Comment: I have a saas application, i want to generate a database for each client that signs up, the idea is how to generate the ( .emdx ) automatically (for now i can generate the connection string automatcally).
so can i generate the (.edmx) for each connection string (i am using database first) because after the sign up each client need to manipulate his own database.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is the same for each client then you don't need a separate model, you just need the correct connection string.

If the database has differences for some/all clients then you also need a separate model and a separate application to use the unique bits of that model.

In any case, there is no way to generate a model at run-time (although I suppose you could code it yourself, though why you'd bother I don't know). Especially with database-first, generating a model in VS is dead easy but it sounds like you don't need to it beyond the once.